# Chrome and Safari javascript .sort() method works differently

Tags: javascript, sorting, browser, safari

I faced with really strange thing (at least it is strange to me).
I am trying to sort items in array but receiving really different result in Chrome and Safari.

Please take a look at my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d9868zus/21/) in CHROME and then in Safari

Chrome has the right order, which should be:

```
Funny Pig 1 

Funny Pig 2 

Funny Pig 3 

Angry Lion 1

Angry Lion 2

Little  Rabbit 1

Little Rabbit 2
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: thoughts: safari is the new internet explorer -

Comment: does safari (I don't safari at all) like it better if you `item.result.sort((a, b) => {
      return animals_order.indexOf(a.name.split(' ')[0]) > animals_order.indexOf(b.name.split(' ')[0]) ? 1 : 
      (animals_order.indexOf(a.name.split(' ')[0]) < animals_order.indexOf(b.name.split(' ')[0]) ? -1 : 0);
    });`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, it works now. In Chrome and Safari. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> The sort is not necessarily [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).

And while you sort only by the name part, up to the first space, the sorting algorithm choose a place for same name, which do not respect the numerical value.

To overcome this problem, you could sort by the numerical value as well.

Any sorting before the last sorting is altered.

You need for strings which have more than one space a different method, because you get with two spaces three elements. Now it uses not numerical values at start and the numerical value at the end of the string.

```js
var animals_order = 'Funny Pig, Angry Lion, Little Rabbit',
    data = [{ result: [{ name: "Angry Lion 2" }, { name: "Funny Pig 1" }, { name: "Funny Pig 2" }, { name: "Angry Lion 1" }, { name: "Funny Pig 3" }, { name: "Little Rabbit 2" }, { name: "Little Rabbit 1" }] }];

function order () {
    data.forEach(item => {
        item.result.sort((a, b) => {
            var [aName, aValue] = a.name.split(/\s(?=\d)/),
                [bName, bValue] = b.name.split(/\s(?=\d)/);

            return animals_order.indexOf(aName) - animals_order.indexOf(bName) || aValue - bValue;
        });
    });
}

function display() {
    data[0].result.forEach(assignment => {
        document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML += "<br />" + assignment.name;
    });
}

order();
display();
```

```html
<div id="divID"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have never faced with such issue before. And interesting that Safari doesn't handle it in a right way without additional manipulation. P.S. Unfortunately your code is still doesn't work well in Safari, because a/bValue equals to the second word not the numerical value.

Comment: The first items are good all the other have reverse order https://monosnap.com/file/iioDXAjGdzuTv93dEsLyKFI20JXO2R

Comment: Here is a link to the screenshot of your answer https://monosnap.com/file/XWgVadKUvD4VV3Cdj6gLpW3iAlnVOZ

Comment: you can also see the same behavior even in chrome.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. In safari and all the other browsers